# How to show already expanded STCollapseTableView for all items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm programmatically coding STCollapseTableView. What I want is when user enters the particular screen, all headers must be expanded by default without clicking any headers. And I don't want other header to be collapsed if one is expanded. Is it possible? If not then what is other way to achieve this?

I have headers and if some of the header items contain child items, it should have expanded already.

Edit: I have figured out that I need to call below method in order to expand headers without clicking.

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    NSInteger index = tap.view.tag;
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        [self toggleSection:(NSUInteger)index animated:YES];
    }
}
```

How can I call this method after all headers are displayed?

I use below code to return cell as header views for my table. So I need to call handleTapGesture() method after reloading tblItems.

```
 [self.headers removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrItems count] ; i++)
    {
        [self.headers addObject:[self addViewintoCell:i]];
    }


    [tblItems reloadData];
    [tblItems setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are one lazy solution, but it couldn't be used as standard solution, that you open all section in loading just after reloading table with your data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setExclusiveSections:NO];

    //Get Section to open
    NSInteger sectionCount = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
    for (int needToOpen = 0; needToOpen<sectionCount; needToOpen++) {
        //Open Section one by one
        [self.tableView openSection:needToOpen animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. And how could you say it isn't a standard solution? Its easy and perfect with causing no errors.

Comment: Generally, change UI state with for loop is not good idea, but from given library there is no other way. So we can go with this solution. You can accept answer, if its work for you.

Comment: for me, It will be standard whatever solve my problem ;)

Comment: I'm a fresher and I want to follow you. I won't bother you much, don't worry :p